# Mobile GTM tagging - GTM+Firebase SDK - Export iOS container and import to Android

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am configuring Google Tag Manager containers for mobile apps (iOS & Android) using latest version of SDK (GTM+Firebase). 
Tracking needs to be 99% identical between iOS and Android apps.

I have created two containers (iOS & Android). **Is there a way to update Android container with changes from iOS container other than manually re-creating each tag/trigger and variable?** For ex: by exporting iOS and importing it into Android container using corresponding options from the Admin section in GTM.